# EADDRNOTAVAIL Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting an  EADDRNOTAVAIL Error as follows:

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL [MYIP]
     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1218:19)
     at listen (net.js:1267:10)
     at net.js:1376:9
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)
```

My NODE app.js settings are set as:

```
// == Server Configuration ==
//
// This is the configuration file for the Node.js Ajax IM server. Here, you
// can set which ports will be used for the public and internal servers,
// as well as other settings such as the session cookie name and expiration.

// === Host and Port ===
//
// Define the host and port that Ajax IM will run on.
APP_HOST = '[MYIP]';
APP_PORT = 8000;

// === Authentication Library ===
//
// This is the library (from libs/authenticate/) that we will use to
// authenticate a user signing in. The value should be the name of the file
// without the '.js' part. 'index' is the default library.
AUTH_LIBRARY = 'default';

// === Daemon ===
//
// Define where the PID and log files will be deposited when run as a daemon.
PID_FILE = '/tmp/ajaxim.pid';
LOG_FILE = '/var/run/ajaxim.log';
```

Comment: I guess you did actually replace `[MYIP]` with your real address (or a valid substitute), right?

Comment: Is `[MYIP]` an IP address associated with one of your network interfaces?

Comment: @mscdex [MYIP] has been replaced with my actual IP. I have censored it so that people do not see it and try to DDOS me

Comment: @still_learning [MYIP] has been replaced with my actual IP. I have censored it so that people do not see it and try to DDOS me

Comment: I guess this is the address the server should bind to. As @mscdex already pointed out, this must be an IP associated with a network interface on the server. If you are behind a router, the public IP address is associated with the router, not with the server machine. Did you try `127.0.0.1`, `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: @still_learning it works on localhost. The router IP won't work however and spits that error.

Comment: Use 0.0.0.0 instead. There’s no reason to specify something exact unless you have multiple accessible IP addresses *and* only want to listen on one of them.

Comment: As @mscdex and I already tried to point out, the address has to be associated with your machine, not with your router. Are you sure that a local IP (`192.168.x.x`, `127.0.0.1`, `localhost` or preferably `0.0.0.0`) is insufficient in your situation? I don't know the server you are using, but most services can be bound to a local address and still be accessed through port forwarding.

Comment: @minitech I've already tried. Won't allow me to connect publicly though.

Comment: @CharlieWilliamPorter: That would be your router’s fault, probably. Look for port forwarding.

Comment: @still_learning so I have to foward the port and then it **should** work?

Comment: @CharlieWilliamPorter If your server is behind a router and provides a network service, the router needs to let incoming packets pass through. That's what port forwarding is for. Yes, it **should** work.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Thanks guys!

Comment: SOLVED @still_learning

Comment: How did you solved this problem, I am facing same issue